# Can't access all rows of a dynamically generated table

Tags: reactjs, powershell, web-scraping, automation, browser-automation

### Background Info

I am attempting to build a web scraper using PowerShell and an Internet Explorer COM Object. The goal of the web scraper is to grab the data from a specific table on the page and store it for use later in the script.

I do not own the website, but I believe it is a ReactJS app, and the table is dynamically populated upon page load.
Below is my code as of now: ('domains-name' is the class name of the rows I'm seeking)

```
$IE= New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"

$IE.navigate2(“https://www.example.com/control_panel")

while ($IE.busy) {
    start-sleep -milliseconds 1000
} 

$IE.visible=$false
$domainAddressArr = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

$IE.Document.IHTMLDocument2_body.getElementsByClassName('domains-name') | 
ForEach-Object {
    $a = $_.children[0]
    [void]$domainAddressArr.Add($a.toString())
}
```

### My Problem

This gets me an array of the correct information, however it is missing 2 rows of data that I can plainly see on the page, and in Chrome's page inspector. Is this perhaps an issue where react isn't rendering the full table until there is user interaction? I've tried adding a 5 second pause before scanning the page, with no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For this kind of job you should have a look to [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) It's easy to use with PowerShell (I can give you the first steps if needed).

Comment: I would suggest simply using `$IE.Document.getElementsByClassName('domains-name')` or if there is an `id` property, use `$IE.Document.getElementById('the-id')`